# Postgres row level policy issue

Tags: postgresql

I am trying out the Postgres row level security feature and not being able to see it working. Not sure what I am missing.

```
CREATE TABLE tenants (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

INSERT INTO tenants (id, name) values ('ec5e9a6b-ed71-4e41-bc1e-11dac6808e41', 'Tenant1'), ('a684edc2-19b2-40d6-b679-519a6f736981', 'Tenant2');

ALTER TABLE tenants ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY ;
ALTER TABLE tenants FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

SET app.tenant_id = 'ec5e9a6b-ed71-4e41-bc1e-11dac6808e41';

CREATE POLICY tenants_policy ON tenants FOR ALL USING ( current_setting('app.tenant_id')::uuid = id );

SELECT * FROM tenants;
```

For the last select, I expected it to return only one row with id 'ec5e9a6b-ed71-4e41-bc1e-11dac6808e41' but it is returning both rows. What am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works for me. There are a few possibilities:

- The current user is a superuser.
- The current user is defined with `BYPASSRLS`.
- The configuration parameter `row_security` is `off`.

Comment: It was the super user (facepalm). Thank you!